# Google Apps Script - Find Sum of Range from Dynamically Changing Tab Names

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 10 tabs with names that keep changing as job finishes with each one. So am using an array to find sheets.

Master sheet needs to display values from same Column in All 10 Tabs AF3:AF

This code can only return a value from 1 cell - not a range.

```
function MasterTotals() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Master Sales');
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14];
var value = sheet.getRange('AF3:AF').getValue();
sheet1.getRange('AM2:AM').setValue(value); 
so [5] should return answer to AM2 - [6] should return answer to AM3 etc etc

Error returned is **cannot read property getRange**

Appreciate any help on what I am not seeing
```

[image]

Comment: _Master sheet needs to display values from same Column in All 10 Tabs AF3:AF_ Could you clarify: do you want to get __a sum__ of column from the sheet [5,6,...] and put it into the cell on your Master sheet, or you want to get __columns__ from these sheets? Since `getRange('AF3:AF')` means a column, not a cell. But you can't put a column into a cell. Probably you need to sum the column first?

Comment: Quote the full error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

- Your goal is to iterate over the sheets starting from the 6th sheet (index 5) to the 15th sheet (index 14). Remember `getSheets()[0]` is the 1st sheet.
- For each sheet, you want to get the total sum of the values in the range `AF3:AF`. To get the sum, I [flatten](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) the 2D array to 1D, [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the empty cells, and then find the sum using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).
- Finally we paste the data back to the `Master Sales` sheet.

### Solution:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Master Sales');
  const sheets = ss.getSheets().slice(5,15);
  const data = [];
  sheets.forEach( sh => 
  data.push([sh.getRange('AF3:AF').getValues().flat().filter(r=>r!='').reduce((a,b)=>a+b)])
 ); 
  sheet1.getRange(2,39,data.length,1).setValues(data); //AM
}
```

**Side Note:**

The proper way to slice an array in javascript is to use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
const sheets = ss.getSheets().slice(5,15);
```

Comment: Hi Marios. I tested code but am only getting the first number in AF3 for the first sheet [5] and last sheet [15].which is a 1. sheet 6-14 remain blank. added image to above post

Comment: @DUBYARX Please try out my new solution. I believe you want to get the sum of values in the range `AF3:AF` for every sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite an answer. Just this lines don't look well:

```
var value = sheet.getRange('AF3:AF').getValue();
sheet1.getRange('AM2:AM').setValue(value);
```

Should'n be there `getValues()` and `setValues()` instead of `getValue()` `setValue()`? Since the ranges include many cells.

`getValue()` and `setValue()` handle only one (first) cell of a range.